# When sorting Outlook 2013 emails by Oldest First there are problems with moving/deleting emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've been experiencing an issue for sometime across several systems with Outlook 2013 that relates to sorting my emails by Oldest First.

I like to have my oldest emails at the top of my mailbox so I can process them in a First In, First Out manner. However, when I move or delete an email the screen will often not refresh to indicate the email has been moved until I manually move down an email. Additionally, sometimes it may get even more confused and jump to some other part of the mailbox (often the very top).

I've not been able to find this issue reported by others but as I've experienced it across multiple systems I'm sure I'm not the only one facing this problem.

I'm running Windows 8.1 and connecting to Exchange via Office 365 (wave 15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook always had this kind of refresh bugs, well before version 2013,
and the scenario you outline is not the only one where it can happen.

Here is a reference to a similar problem from 2011 :
[When sorting using "oldest on top", reading pane always repositions to OLDEST messages instead of newest](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/when-sorting-using-oldest-on-top-reading-pane/93df5d8f-e765-4bd9-bd9d-11605e07e243).

The advice normally given in such cases is :

- Try using a new Outlook profile
- Restart Outlook
- Click/unclick "show in groups" will refresh without having to restart
- Refresh cache for IMAP or Exchange accounts
- Revert to a previous copy of Microsoft Office

Please add to your post your operating-system version and whether you are connecting
to an Exchange server.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not so sure I see an answer for my question in here. However, there may not be an answer to this question beyond "Microsoft needs to get their crap together."

Comment: Yes, in effect this is a bug and only Microsoft can fix it. But normally such long-running bugs are rarely fixed. You may leave a comment about the problem at this [Microsoft page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/suggestions.aspx) or int the [Microsoft forums](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home) or the [Microsoft community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/outlook?tab=Threads).